# Update tableView with AccessoryCheckmark when switching back to that TabView

Tags: iphone

My app has 3 tabs, and the array that populates a tableView in third tab can be changed in the other two tabs. When I switch to the third tab, I need the tableView to be updated. I know how to do this, the only problem is that the table view is a check list.

When I tick some of the rows in the third tab, switch to another tab and update the 3rd tab's array, when I want to switch back to the third tab the table is updated with the new data but the checkmarks are removed from the table.

Is there a way to update the table without removing the checkmarks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you determining whether an item is checked right now?  It sounds like you may not be storing the checked status of the object, and instead just setting the `accessoryType` on the cell to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`.  If so you need to add a boolean property to the objects stored in the array that will represent whether that item is currently checked or not.

Once you have this value stored you can use it when configuring your tableview cells(either in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or `configureCell: atIndexPath:` or wherever else you do cell configuration) to set the appropriate `accessoryType` for the cell..  Putting this in your cell configuration will get the tableview to correctly check items when reloading the tableview.

Comment: Hi David thanks for your reply. How would I assign a boolean value to each of the objects in the array? Is there a way without having to write it out to a file? I don't need it to remain between app launches, just between view switches. Cheers

Comment: What type of objects are you storing in the array?  If they are instances of a custom class then you can simply add a boolean property to that class that would store the value.  The value would not persist between app launches, but would remain valid as long as the object is alive.  If you're not using a class of your own making a simple solution would be a wrapper class that would contain the object you were storing in the array(an NSString for example) as well as the boolean property.

Answer (score 0):

Are you reloading the tableview when you tap on 3rd button or creating new tableView.

If you are reloading, Use **temp** variable to store the data of Checkmarked cell. On every reload compare the **temp** data with data of cell .If it matchs place checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

when you are adding objects to the array then there you can add a dictionary object, with an extra object @"FALSE",@"checkState". Initially it will FALSE for all objects, so when you are creating cells for table in your third tab check for that key in array. And when you select a cell then access the dictionary object for that indexPath.row in array and update its value to TRUE for key @"checkState".